# Cannot override onVectorElementClicked from MapEventListener

Tags: carto, c#

According to carto (https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/mobile-sdk/developer-guide-to-sdk-features/), the function `OnVectorElementClicked` can be overwritten if it extends from `MapEventListener`. But I could not find it in Rider (using Xamarin (C#) Android).

Am I missing something ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation features a note:

> NOTE: This is a map event listener, if you wish to listen to vector
>   element clicks, implement VectorElementEventListener in a similar
>   fashion and attach it to a Vectorlayer

So, you need to inherit from VectorElementEventListener, not MapEventListener.

However, you are correct, that part can be a bit confusing. We'll make improvements.

Comment: Seems to be the same case for Android. Thank you for the clarification @Nikitah, I was confused as well while reading the documentation.